# Datomic and Spark Streaming - Data consistency

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, datomic

I have some question around Datomic and Spark streaming.

As per my knowledge in Spark streaming when a job runs (assume it is consuming data from a kafka topic (single partition - fully ordered)), its  micro-batches / Dstream's of RDD can run on different executors for example micro-batch B1 at time T1 can run on executor/node E1 and next micro-batch B2 at time T1 + delta can run on different executor/node E2.

Given this if batch B1 runs on executor/node E1 and the next batch B2 runs on executor/node E2, will there be any problems with respect to correctness of data? For example in batch B1 running on executor E1 for entity EN1 I want to update some attribute say Name to Sam, I do the change and DB gets updated. After this, in batch B2 running on executor E2 for the same entity EN1 I want to update other attribute say Occupation to Business, I do the change and DB gets updated. But at this point executor E2 has entity EN1 in its cache whose Name is not updated to Sam - pointing to Old value say John (changes made on executor E1 in earlier batch B1 have still not reached to executor E2). Now on executor E2 if I try to read the attributes Name and Occupation of EN1, I may get Name as John (old value) and Occupation as Business (new value).

How to ensure that I get latest value of entity attributes on READ from any node irrespective of where (which node) the update happened?

Comment: Just making sure: it seems that this question is not really related to Datomic? Spark is not one of the storage backends that Datomic supports.

Comment: Hi, in this case Spark is not the backend. Datomic's backend is Cassandra. Spark is an execution engine which schedules jobs. These jobs use Datomic to either insert/update (WRITE) or READ the records/entities based on the input that is passed (RDD). Spark can schedule these jobs on any Executor.

Comment: But your question is not really Datomic related, right? Asking because I know a lot about Datomic but nothing about Spark :) Seems like your question is about how Spark behaves.

Comment: My question is about Datomic when it runs on Spark. From Datomic documents I understand how Datomic works. But when it comes to Spark, the way Spark schedules jobs is different. For ex. a program that is writing to or reading from/to a Datomic entity will behave correctly (i.e. read will always return consistent upto-date data that was written) if the program runs on same machine. But in Spark this same program may run on one machine at one time and on other machine at other time.

Comment: So, if this program writes something from one machine and then runs on other machine and tries to read this data, then it may not get latest upto date data. So the way Spark schedules this program on different machines makes the difference and I think some care has to be taken with that in mind.